# Mail Commander plugin in Jenkins cannot trigger Parameterized build

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I am trying to build parameterized jobs in Jenkins through Mail commander plugin.

As per the documentation of the plugin I have configured it. It triggers stand alone jobs which don't need any parameters.

It also builds parameterized jobs but with default values.

MailCommander plugin reads the subject and builds the specific trigger.

I give the command as "build jobname -p key=value -p key=value" but the MailCommander just ignores the parameters.

Please let me know if there is some other configuration that I have to do.